# problema con enumeraciones en c++

Tags: c++, enum

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum class nota {DO,RE,MI,FA,SOL,LA,SI};
    nota a;
    nota b;
    int iA,iB;
    cin >> iA >> iB;
    switch(iA)
    {
        case 1:{
            a = nota::DO;
        }break;

        default:{
        }break;

    }

    cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Quiero hacer un programa de teoria musical y pense usar enum para los nombres de las notas
pero al compilar me agarra con un error en `a = nota::DO;`
estoy usando codeblocks y en los build messages sale:
warning: scoped enums only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
error: 'nota' is not a class or namespace

Comment: En el tab de Projects selecciona el archivo, click derecho > Properties > Advanced. Cambia `Compiler variable` de `CC` por `CPP`.

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando una enumeración acotada (*scoped enum*), este tipo de enumeración fue introducida en el estándar C++11, es lo la alarma (no error) te está indicando (te lo traduzco):

> warning: scoped enums only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

> alarma: las enumeraciones acotadas sólo están disponibles con -std=c++11 o -std=gnu++11

Dado que no reconoce ese tipo de enumeración, la ignora y por ello surge el error posterior:

> error: 'nota' is not a class or namespace

> error: 'nota' no es una clase o espacio de nombres

El error no surge porque `nota::DO` sea incorrecto si no porque al no haberlo reconocido antes, actúa como si no lo reconociera después.

Tienes dos opciones:

- **NO RECOMENDADO** Cambia a enumerado tradicional:

  ```
  enum nota {DO,RE,MI,FA,SOL,LA,SI};
  ```
- Actualiza tu compilador a una versión C++11 o superior (recomiendo C++17).